# Convert Jquery to VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to rewrite this code from Jquery to VanillaJS. I've been tired for a few days and I haven't found a solution.

I think I've already searched the whole Internet and found nothing...
Can someone give me a "ready" code? Please help me one more time.

```js
const menuIconEl = $('.menu-icon');
const sidenavEl = $('.sidenav');
const sidenavCloseEl = $('.sidenav-close-icon');

function toggleClassName(el, className) {
  if (el.hasClass(className)) {
    el.removeClass(className);
  } else {
    el.addClass(className);
  }
}
menuIconEl.on('click', function() {
  toggleClassName(sidenavEl, 'active');
});
sidenavCloseEl.on('click', function() {
  toggleClassName(sidenavEl, 'active');
});
```

The whole code after using the Jquery works, but after each attempt to convert it to vanillaJS it no longer works.

Comment: Why do you need that? Almost every application runs on jQuery / support jQuery. If you want to use any particular framework then you should ask to change code in that framework. Otherwise adding jQuery should be piece of cake without compromising any design paradigm. Better if you use CDN.

Comment: use querySelector() instead of $().
use addEventlistener() instead of on()
use classList.add() instead of addClass()

Comment: Have a look at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), that should be all you need

Comment: @Akshay jQuery was very good ten years ago, but today you get these features for free in the browser _natively_. jQuery is a giant library of which most people use one or two features, and none of them are necessary. This attitude of 'just add jQuery' will lead to cruft, and to bloated code. If you can remove it, remove it.

Comment: BTW with jQuery, the `toggleClassName` was redundant - jQuery has a `toggleClass` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When selecting things, you can use

```
document.querySelector( query:String ) // returns an HTMLElement or null
document.querySelectorAll( query:String ) // returns a NodeList you can iterate over
```

For toggling classes, you can use `classList` and its methods to control classes on HTMLElements:

```
HTMLElement.classList.toggle( className:String, forced:Boolean|Null )
```

And for adding event listeners, just use `addEventListener` instead of `on`.

This turns your code into this:

```
const menuIconEl = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');
const sidenavEl = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
const sidenavCloseEl = document.querySelector('.sidenav-close-icon');
const onclick = e => sidenavEl.classList.toggle( 'active' );

menuIconEl.addEventListener( 'click', onclick );
sidenavCloseEl.addEventListener( 'click', onclick );
```

And that does it!

Comment: My bad, I though they triggered different effects, so fixed it. I also made your function a single arrow function that can be reused, as they contain _exactly_ the same code so no need to duplicate that, and it makes the code look even simpler.

Comment: @keith Yeah, true. jQuery's `on` has some fricking obscure features that I never use :D Removed that line.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I would find fantastic people on this forum

Comment: @MAJO be aware that I used an arrow function (one with `=>`), that onloy works on modern browsers. Usually developers let a script convert it to something your list of required browsers support. You can easily replace it with `function(){ ... }`. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

Few examples below. You might be interested in website [YouMightNotNeedJquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
$('.menu-icon');
// can be replaced with:
document.querySelector('.menu-icon');
```

```
el.hasClass(className);
// can be replaced with:
el.classList.contains(className);
```

```
el.addClass(className);
// can be replaced with:
el.classList.add(className);
```

```
el.removeClass(className);
// can be replaced with:
el.classList.remove(className);
```

> Can someone give me a "ready" code?

No. You should learn it by yourself.